# Teradata set time zone and DST for session

Tags: timezone, teradata, dst

Due to certain reasons, I need to change the time zone on the session level in Teradata.
To achieve this, I can use the following command:

`SET TIME Zone 'America Argentina'`

However, even though there is no Daylight Saving Time observed in this time zone, I still want to specify the DST period. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I searched the documentation but couldn't find the exact command

Comment: I don't understand, those time zone strings automatically adjust for DST. Argentina no longer uses DST, but you still want it? You can also set the offset from UTC: `SET TIME ZONE -3` but this is applied to timestamps before 2009, too.

Comment: Daylight Saving Time adjustments are based on [GetTimeZoneDisplacement](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/SQL-Date-and-Time-Functions-and-Expressions/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions/GetTimeZoneDisplacement)  UDF, so if none of the supplied time zones satisfy your requirement there is the possibility to customize.